# Laravel 8 Project on Plesk keeps blank Main Page

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, plesk

I have a laravel 8 project (precompiled) on a Plesk server where the main page keeps blank without any errors in log (apache log and laravel debug log). The subpages are working. Also when using e.g. mainpage.com/login the page loads correctly and after login function/form the redirect goes to the mainpage which is also showing , when reloading the main page and/or going there directly the page is blank.
Plesk is configured to use the root folder and the rest should be managed by htaccess.

Here is my .htaccess from root diretory:

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/install\.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>
```

And this is the .htaccess from the /public folder:

```
     <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     Options -MultiViews -Indexes
     </IfModule>

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
     RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
     RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
     </IfModule>
```

My .env looks like this:

```
     APP_KEY=base64:CgplgmocYbK1qBb3nZcukDrOlxhx+KYGgFT+uKxoyDU=
     LOCALE=en
     DB_CONNECTION=mysql
     DB_HOST=localhost
     DB_PORT=3306
     DB_DATABASE=xxx
     DB_USERNAME=xxxx
     DB_PASSWORD=xxx
     MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
     MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
     MAIL_PORT=2525
     MAIL_USERNAME=
     MAIL_PASSWORD=
     MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
     APP_DEBUG=false
     APP_LOG_LEVEL=emergency
     SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=xxx-xxx.com
     APP_URL="https://xxx-xxx.com"
     FORCE_SSL=TRUE
```